# How do I use async pipe instead of using subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-pipe

I would like to use the async pipe "| async" instead of subscribing. This is what my subscription code currently looks like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.url
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(segments => {
        this.quizName = segments[1].toString();
      });
}
```

and in my template I have: `<mat-card *ngIf="quiz.quizId === quizName">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this :

```js
quizName$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.quizName$ = this.activatedRoute.url
    .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
      map(segments => segments[1].toString()); // Not sure about this part
    );
}
```

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="(quizName$ | async) === quiz.quizId">
```

Be careful, everytime you will use async pipe in your template, it will make a subscribe.

Answer (score 3):

Add variable:

```
quizName$ = this.activatedRoute.url.pipe(map(segments => segments[1].toString()));
```

1. no need for `takeUntil` such as "| async" does it
2. optional(your IDE would know about it by itself)

```
quizName$: Observable<string> ...
```

in HTML:

```
*ngIf="(quizName$ | async) === quiz.quizId"
```

**more "robust" solution**

```
showQuiz$: Observable<boolean> = this.activatedRoute.url.pipe(
  map(segments => segments[1].toString()),
  map(quizName => quizName === this.quiz && this.quiz.id)
);
```

```
*ngIf="showQuiz$ | async"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm going the previous solution because it's simpler and I'm retrieving quizId from a for loop in the template.

Comment: np ;) tip: loops, ifs, etc - it is mixing imperative and reactive(rx)/functional programming. it is possible to arrange streams with different operators(and creational observables).

Comment: about quiz - though it was Input

Comment: @andriishupta Thanks for your answer ! I didn't know `async` pipe could manage `takeUntil` :)